# scons error "sh: 1: arm-none-eabi-gcc: not found''

Tags: c++, linux, scons, newlib

in my project, i using both Scons and Makefile to build. It working good when i use Makefile ,but got error when i use Scons

> "arm-none-eabi-gcc -g -mthumb -mlittle-endian -mcpu=cortex-m4
>   -mcpu=cortex-m4 -Wl,--start-group -lm -lc -Wl,--end-group -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-Map,main.map -Tstm32_flash.ld -Wl,--entry=Reset_Handler -DSTM32F407xx -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER -I/home/minhtan/Downloads/STM32F4-Discovery_FW_V1.1.0/Utilities/STM32F4-Discovery
>   -I/home/minhtan/Downloads/STM32F4-Discovery_FW_V1.1.0/Libraries/CMSIS/Include
>   -I/home/minhtan/Downloads/STM32F4-Discovery_FW_V1.1.0/Libraries/CMSIS/ST/STM32F4xx/Include
>   -I/home/minhtan/Downloads/STM32F4-Discovery_FW_V1.1.0/Libraries/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/inc
>   "-I/home/minhtan/Downloads/led(make file moi)" main.c -c -o
>   main.o
>  sh: 1: arm-none-eabi-gcc: not found
>  scons:
>   [main.o] Error 127
>   scons: building terminated because of errors. "

Comment: Well, do you have `arm-none-eabi-gcc` installed?

Comment: Yes, i have arm-none-eabi-gcc installed. version "gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_4-2016q2-20160622-linux" and i add PATH to /etc/profile "export PATH:$PATH=/otc/gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_4-2016q2-20160622-linux/bin" but it error

Comment: Can you type  `arm-none-eabi-gcc` at the command line? (to check the `PATH` is properly set). I mean is `/otc` correct? Should that be `/opt`?

Comment: oh sory ,in my profile is /opt

Comment: in my Scons have :** # Cross compile setup <br/> cross_prefix = 'arm-none-eabi-' <br/> env.Replace(CC = cross_prefix + 'gcc') <br/> env.Replace(CXX = cross_prefix + 'g++') <br/> env.Replace(LINK = cross_prefix + 'gcc') <br/> env.Replace(AR = cross_prefix + 'ar') <br/> env.Replace(RANLIB = cross_prefix + 'ranlib') <br/> **

Comment: If they are not to long it may be worth adding the `Makefile` that works and the `Scons` file that doesn't work to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the answer to #1 of our "most frequently asked" FAQs at http://scons.org/faq.html could help you out. By default, SCons doesn't import the variables like `$PATH` from the surrounding shell environment. You have to pull in your `$PATH` for properly detecting the `arm-none-eabi-gcc` executable or specify the full path to the executable explicitly...check the mentioned FAQ entry for a more detailed discussion about why things are as they are, and how to provide the required `$PATH` definitions to your build environments.

Comment: dirkbaechle : when i used ubuntu 14.04, it work good. but when i using ubuntu 16.04, it error. I think, the cause lies in the version of ubuntu is using